# Progressive Enhancement on form (submission)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, progressive-enhancement

I have a form with `<input type="submit id="no-js-submit">`.

If Javascript is enabled I am removing this `submit`-input field by `$('#no-js-submit').remove();` and add the "fire-ajax"-button with

`$('<button id="fire-ajax" type="button">Fire Ajax</button>').appendTo('#tk-form');`.

So, if JavaScript is enabled (and if jQuery is able to remove the submit-input field) the form's values will be transfered to the server by ajax.

If JS is disabled (and therefore jQuery cannot remove the submit-input) the form's values will be submitted by the `<input type="submit id="no-js-submit">`.

What do you think about this solution? Is there any browser (in-)compatibility I should worry about? Furthermore, is there any best practice to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to do it is just build a normal form that submits the data the usual way. Without JS, this should work as advertised.

If JS is enabled, you can simply "hi-jack" the form's submit event, prevent it from happening, and do everything in JS from this point onwards. No need to replace DOM elements.

```
$('yourFormSelector').on('submit',function(event){

  // Prevent the form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Turns the form into a JS Objec
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/575527
  var formData = $(this).serializeObject();

  // Do AJAX magic here
});
```

To gather the form data, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/575527) contains a very handy method that gathers named and enabled form inputs and turns them into a JS object. You can use this function to gather the form data and feed it to your AJAX call.

Comment: Is it possible to access the form values at `// Do AJAX magic here` by an other method than `$('#foo').val();`?

Comment: @Thommy I linked [a method which exactly does that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/575527). It's a jQuery "plugin".